# LSTM: Diffrent y size after splitting X on timesteps

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

After following some tutorials on **LSTM networks**, I've decided to put my knowledge in practice by training a LSTM model on my own dataset.

Here is a view of my data:

[image]

As you can observe, I have same number of samples and labels.

Let's say that I have 10 samples and 10 labels for those samples and I want to split those samples in 2 timesteps.
After spliting I would have 5 samples, each having 2 timesteps, but I would still have 10 labels.
Am I right?

How you guys deal with this problem?

If I'm trying to feed the data in this form, I will get  a "*Data cardinality is ambiguous*" exception.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about DL theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

In an LSTM, every input sequence has one one label (in the case of simple classification, at least). So in your case you would have your data be two samples of the position, and then a single label.